# angular-xeditable select is not saving

Tags: javascript, angularjs, select, x-editable

I have created an application in angularjs with xeditable plugin, The application is working fine but the issue is that when i click the edit button and change the select option to some other, and when click save, it is not saving, I am having a nested json for status field like as shown below

http://jsfiddle.net/yspbcfuL/

Can anyone tell me some solution for this

```
 $scope.users = [
     {id: 1, name: 'awesome user1', status: {uid: 2, text: 'status2'}, group: 4, groupName: 'admin'},
    {id: 2, name: 'awesome user2', status: undefined, group: 3, groupName: 'vip'},
    {id: 3, name: 'awesome user3', status: {uid: 2, text: 'status2'}, group: null}
  ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

{{ user.status }} contains only object like this {uid:#} when you pick value that`s the problem, you can solve this as same as you solved groups

change

```
{{user.status}}
```

to

```
{{showStatus(user)}}
```

and change your showStatus method, beacuse its wrong

```
  selected = $filter('filter')($scope.statuses, {value: user.status});//old and wrong
  selected = $filter('filter')($scope.statuses, {uid: user.status.uid}); // correct
```

Comment: can you share me a jsfiddle

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yspbcfuL/1/ as i saw u have method showStatus but u have there a wrong filter